# AMPscript in HTML - check c

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, appexchange, code

I'm writing a code for personalize an email with
product name , image, price (all in the same lines, three "boxes)

The current layout include a visualization of up to 4 products and a structure like a "grid".

As this is the fist time i do this I was looking for some app able to support me in check the code I'm writing and confirming I putting in the right position in the HTML.
I read there was one in AppExchange called AMPscript Editor but I can't find it. 
How could I do this check? Thanks for your suggestion
G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all honesty, the AMPscript editor in SFMC App Exchange is not all that great. If you are used to using a third party editor for your coding, I would look to instead utilize a plugin that highlights AMPscript issues ([Adam made a custom one for Sublime](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/240781/is-there-any-ampscript-live-editor-available) based off [this one](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AmpScript%20Highlighter)). [Here](https://medium.com/@charlie.fay/essential-tools-for-the-sfmc-practitioner-ac3963bd54f7) is a decent list of available ones - but honestly, searching the plugins for AMPscript will likely give you more options on what to find.

Although using an add-on in your environment is helpful, the only way to 100% verify/validate the code is through Email Preview or CloudPage viewing.  There is no way to compile the AMPscript outside of the platform so there is no 'live editor'.

The best option to do this is to utilize an external 'publicly available' online resource (Dropbox, etc) that can be accessed via URL and then create a Cloudpage and use [HTTPGET()](https://ampscript.guide/book/httpget) to this URL so you can just refresh the page and have your code rendered.  The issue here is that each CloudPage view costs a SuperMessage, so this can get expensive really quickly.

I have found that creating a blank HTML email and using the same HTTPGET trick above (or using a 'ContentBlockBy...' and have the code in a Content Block works well too. This would have the added step of you would need to toggle back and forth on the preview part to get the most recent view instead of just a page refresh...but it is also free.